# Apache Spark throws exception when I try to persist RDD into mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

I am trying to do a simple retrieval (which works fine) from mongodb to use it as as Spark's RDD. The problem is that it throws Driver stacktrace when I save it using Hadoop API. The interesting part is that it does open the connection with my local mongodb instance on save as I can see in mongodb's connection open/end logs. Below is code code snippet, pom.xml and exception it throws. Also, I am using the following Mongodb connector for Hadoop:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop

```
SparkConf sc = new SparkConf()
                    .setMaster("local[3]")
                    .setAppName("Spark-Mongo demo");
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);

mgconfig.set("mongo.job.input.format",
        "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat");

mgconfig.set("mongo.input.uri",
        "mongodb://localhost:27017/test.apSlime");

JavaPairRDD<Object, BSONObject> documents = jsc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        mgconfig,            // Configuration
        MongoInputFormat.class,   // InputFormat: read from a live cluster.
        Object.class,             // Key class
        BSONObject.class          // Value class
);

Configuration outputConfig = new Configuration();

outputConfig.set("mongo.job.output.format",
    "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat");

outputConfig.set("mongo.output.uri",
        "mongodb://localhost:27017/test.spark");  

documents.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
        "file:///this-is-completely-unused",
        Object.class,
        BSONObject.class,
        MongoOutputFormat.class,
        outputConfig
);
```

Exception:

```
16:12:57.055 ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:909)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:890)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:787)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter.<init>(MongoRecordWriter.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(MongoOutputFormat.java:46)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1107)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1922)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1074)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1074)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1074)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile$2.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:994)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile$2.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:985)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile$2.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:985)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:985)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(JavaPairRDD.scala:800)
    at javademo.SparkMongoDemo.main(SparkMongoDemo.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:909)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:890)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:787)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter.<init>(MongoRecordWriter.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(MongoOutputFormat.java:46)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1107)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Jas.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<!--    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>-->

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```